# "Жил — дрожал(,) и умирал — дрожал"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Надо ли ставить запятую перед союзом "и"?

**Жил — дрожал, и умирал — дрожал.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Жил  — дрожал, и умирал  — дрожал** (из сказки "Премудрый пискарь").

Это е**динственный вариант постановки знаков препинания** в этом предложении.

Здесь можно выделить 4 предикативных односоставных основы:  **Когда (он) жил, то дрожал, когда (он) умирал, то дрожал (тоже).**

Запятая делит предложение на две смысловых блока,  каждый блок — это аналог БСП с временным значением, в этом случае ставится тире.

[Пунктуация. § 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении. / Розенталь: Справочник по русскому языку](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151)

Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в первой части указывается время совершения действия, о котором говорится во второй части (в начале первой части можно добавить союз когда): Победим — каменный дом построишь (А. Т.); Ехал сюда — рожь начинала желтеть.

Comment: В остальных случаях перед союзами "и", "или", "либо", которые соединяют два бессоюзных предложения, запятая не ставится? Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти это правило. У Розенталя об этом ничего не говорится.

Comment: Здесь у нас союзная и бессоюзная связь. В основе всего сложного предложения  лежит союзная связь (союз И) между БСП 1 и БСП2. А в каждом бессоюзном предложении (БСП1 и БСП2)  ставится тире.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за объяснение!