Запятая между двумя блоками БСП с общей бессоюзной связью

Отпустите — уйду и не отпустите — уйду: всё равно дома делать
нечего.

Требуется ли запятая после «уйду» (в оригинале запятой нет)?
По идее, запятая ставиться должна, как в этом случае: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/438278/Жил-дрожал-и-умирал-дрожал/438279#438279.
Смущает, однако, наличие третьей части, общей для обоих блоков БСП. По правилу [п. 2 (3)]:

Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного
предложения третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними
бессоюзной связью…

С одной стороны, не этот случай, т. к. общая часть здесь располагается в конце, а не предшествует другим частям СП (да и применимо ли правило для конструкции такого типа?). С другой стороны, нашел и вот такой ответ, который игнорирует это правило, похожий случай есть и на «Грамоте».

Я бы записала так:
(1) Отпустите — уйду, и не отпустите — уйду. Всё равно дома делать нечего.
Этот вариант предпочтительнее, сообщение делится на две самостоятельные фразы.
(2)  Отпустите — уйду, и не отпустите — уйду, всё равно дома делать нечего.
Связь сочинительная (союз И) и бессоюзная  (значение присоединительное, ставится запятая) При этом деление предложения на две части обозначено неясно.
Но рассмотрим предложенный вариант:
Отпустите — уйду и не отпустите — уйду: всё равно дома делать нечего.
Пояснение

Знаки выглядят неестественно, такое впечатление, что запись текста подобрана под правило. А правило говорит о том, что запятая может не ставиться между двумя простыми предложениями в составе ССП при наличии общего элемента (в данном случае бессоюзной связи). Но можно ли объединить союзом И два сложных предложения, причем это тоже БСП.

По семантике можно было бы, сравнить: С разрешения уйду и без разрешения уйду — всё равно дома делать нечего.

Но по грамматике, по правилам и по интонации  объединение невозможно. Интонационно мы не можем обозначить тире, там будет произношение без паузы.

И тогда делаем вывод и необходимости редактировать предложение с точки зрения знаков. Варианты предложены в начале ответа.


